# Pre vs post increment operator profiling results

Tags: c, performance, profiling, post-increment, pre-increment

I was profiling the pre vs post increment operator in C (out of curiosity, not for micro-optimization purposes!), and I got some surprising results. I expected the post increment operator to be slower, but all of my tests show that it's (non-trivially) faster. I've even looked at the assembly code generated by using the `-S` flag in gcc, and post has one extra instruction (as expected). Can anyone explain this? I'm using gcc 4.8.1 on Arch Linux.

Here is my code.

EDIT: There is an integer overflow error in my code. It doesn't effect the question, but you should note the actual number of iterations is different from the argument passed in.

Post.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Missing required argument\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int iterations = atoi(argv[1]);

    int x = 1;
    int y;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        y = x++;
    }

    printf("%d\n", y);
}
```

Pre.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Missing required argument\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int iterations = atoi(argv[1]);

    int x = 1;
    int y;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        y = ++x;
    }

    printf("%d\n", y);
}
```

Here are the results:

```
$ gcc post.c -o post
$ gcc pre.c -o pre
$ I=100000000000; time ./post $I; time ./pre $I
1215752192

real    0m2.777s
user    0m2.777s
sys     0m0.000s
1215752193

real    0m3.140s
user    0m3.137s
sys     0m0.003s
```

I also wrote a [timing script](https://gist.github.com/gsingh93/6384663) a while ago. Running that gave the same results:

```
$ I=100000000000; comptime "./pre $I" "./post $I"
3193 3133 3157 3143 3133 3153 3147 3150 3143 3146 3143
2743 2767 2700 2727 2700 2697 2727 2710 2680 2783 2700
Mean 1: 3149.18
Mean 2: 2721.27
SD 1: 6.1800
SD 2: 21.2700
```

The output is mostly self explanatory, but the idea is that it runs both programs 10 times (by default) and calculates the mean and standard deviation of the results in milliseconds.

I've included the assembly code generated by gcc for [post.c](http://pastebin.com/sneGDN2h) and [pre.c](http://pastebin.com/gcsBgnJr) on pastebin, since I didn't want to clutter this post with things that might be unnecessary.

Sorry for bringing this debate up again, but these numbers just seem strange to me.

Comment: Make `y` volatile and run it again just for kicks. After that, throw out `x` entirely, remove the increment-step from both for-loops, and just use `y = ++i;` (and `i++` respectively, obviously). I know what it does on my rig, curious about yours. A [similar test](http://ideone.com/W67iOv) just for interest, though it is C++ code.

Comment: @WhozCraig. Very cool. The times are nearly identical.

Comment: @WhozCraig Removing the volatile doesn't change much.

Comment: Well, 100000000000 doesn't fit in a regular `int`. Stick a `printf("%d", iterations);` after your `atoi()` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Emmet, ahh, that's a dumb mistake. I should have realized from the output. Don't think it's related to the question but I'll fix it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I started this as a comment, but it got a bit long.

So, here's what I did, I ran `pre` and `post` like this:

```
$ for i in $(seq 1 10); do command time -f "%U" ./pre 1000000000 2> pre.times
$ echo 'd=load("pre.times"); min(d), mean(d), max(d), std(d)' | octave -q
```

I got (I've substituted for `ans` to make it more readable):

```
min =  2.2900
avg =  2.3550
max =  2.4000
std =  0.040893
```

I ran `post` analogously and got:

```
min =  2.1900
avg =  2.2590
max =  2.3800
std =  0.055668
```

In short, I see a very much smaller difference with an Ivy Bridge CPU and gcc 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 amd64.

Disassembly reveals only a slight reordering of instructions, with no extra instruction (and I wonder why you expected it).

My best guess is that this is an extremely subtle CPU issue like, maybe, a µop spending one more cycle in the reservation station waiting for operand forwarding. It's nothing super-obvious on my setup, that's for sure.